# Build fails on CI pipeline

Tags: azure

I am  trying  to  build  a  CI pipeline,  which is failing with an error  "

Creating deployment parameters. ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

### [error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern

am not understanding what to be the path  exactly is  ?  am    copying the path where the  Json file is (which is local)(C:\Testrepos\Templates\TestDEVOPS\dep?loy.json, is this  correct? what  could be the linked artifact?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are getting the error in the task, Azure resource group deployment, right?

You have to upload your ARM templates to some place that Devops can access, not your local, normally I use a blob storage.

Then you put you ARM template urls in his box.

[image]

**Your ARM templates have to be uploaded somewhere available on the internet for devops to access them. This is the key.**

I hope this help you!